# Is there a way to access DataAnnotations when building MVC3 EditorFor templates?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, templates, data-annotations, editorfor

Suppose I have a view model with a property that looks something like this:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Your name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I want to build an EditorFor template that looks something like this:

```
<label>
    @Model.DisplayName
    @if (Model.Required)
    {
        <span class="required">*</span>
    }
<label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model)
```

Obviously, the above will fail (`Model.Required` and `Model.DisplayName`), but I'm just using that as an example of what I'm trying to do.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model metadata is available from `ViewData`, ie.

`ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName()`

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked well for me by creating a helper method to work out if the [Required] attribute is present or not:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RequiredSymbolFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    string symbol = "*",
    string cssClass = "editor-field-required")
{
    ModelMetadata modelMetadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

    if (modelMetadata.IsRequired)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("span");
        builder.AddCssClass(cssClass);
        builder.InnerHtml = symbol;

        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString("");
}
```

<s>http://www.kristofclaes.be/blog/2011/08/26/an-htmlhelper-to-display-if-a-field-is-required-or-not-in-aspnet-mvc-3/</s>

https://web.archive.org/web/20130711024856/http://www.kristofclaes.be/blog/2011/08/26/an-htmlhelper-to-display-if-a-field-is-required-or-not-in-aspnet-mvc-3/